# Insert data to ElasticSearch using NEST API

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to insert\bulk insert data to Elastic using NEST API.

Can someone provide me the example using NEST?

Thanks,
Sameer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NEST documantation](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/core/bulk.html) contains examples how to do this e.g.:

```
var descriptor = new BulkDescriptor();

foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 1000))
{
    descriptor.Index<ElasticSearchProject>(op => op
        .Document(new ElasticSearchProject {Id = i})
    );
}

var result = client.Bulk(descriptor);
```

Also you can use `IndexMany` which is quite useful

```
var documents= new List<ElasticSearchProject> {...};
client.IndexMany(documents);
```

Good luck.

Comment: Hi Rob,
I have a question. I know NEST is strongly typed. But is there any way to push JSON string to ElasticSearch instead of using classes?

Comment: For raw queries you can still use [NEST](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1427), but in case of indexing data you should have look at [Elasticsearch.Net](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/elasticsearch-net/building-requests.html) I guess. Hope it helps you.